# Appending multiple results from context to one list (result) is not working c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm working on small .net app, and I need to get articles by it's type, there are 3 possible types:

- food
- drink
- candy

I'm wondering what if I want in same list articles with Food and Drinks, how can I add results of context to another result, without reseting it..

Here is my current code:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Article>> GetArticlesByType(ArticleObject request)
{
var result = new Article[] { }.AsQueryable();
IQueryable<ArticleDTO> query = null;

if (request.Food.HasValue && (bool)request.Food)
{
    // Return type of query is IQueryable<Article> 
    query = _context.Articles.Where(x => x.Active == true && x.ArticleType == ArticleType.Food).Select(x => new Article
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        ArticleName = x.ArticleName
    });
    // Here I just wanted if this condition is satisfied to add values to my result
    result.AsQueryable().Union(query);
}

if (request.Drink.HasValue && (bool)request.Drink)
{
    query = _context.Articles.Where(x => x.Active == true && x.ArticleType == ArticleType.Drink).Select(x => new Article
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        ArticleName = x.ArticleName
    });
    // Again if there are any values in query add them to existing result values
    result.AsQueryable().Union(query);
}

if (request.Candy.HasValue && (bool)request.Candy)
{
    // When its candy I want also articles from food category
    query = _context.Articles.Where(x => x.Active == true && x.ArticleType == ArticleType.Food || x.ArticleType==ArticleType.Candy).Select(x => new Article
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        ArticleName = x.ArticleName
    });
    // Again if there are values in query add them to existing result 
    result.AsQueryable().Union(query);
}
//At the end return result and all the values in case all conditions were satisfied
return await result.ToListAsync();
```

}

Right now each I've tried adding values to `result` variable, but all the time result is empty even if `query` has some data.

query is returning `IQueryable<Article>` so I couldn't create empty list of whatever of Interface because I can not intatiate it..

Thanks guys
Cheers

Thanks guys

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Article>> GetArticlesByType(ArticleObject request)
{
    IQueryable<ArticleDTO> foodArticles= null;
    IQueryable<ArticleDTO> drinkArticles= null;
    IQueryable<ArticleDTO> candyArticles= null;

    if (request.Food.HasValue && (bool)request.Food)
    {
        foodArticles= _context.Articles.Where(x => x.Active == true && x.ArticleType == ArticleType.Food).Select(x => new Article
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            ArticleName = x.ArticleName
        });
    }

    if (request.Drink.HasValue && (bool)request.Drink)
    {
        drinkArticles= _context.Articles.Where(x => x.Active == true && x.ArticleType == ArticleType.Drink).Select(x => new Article
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            ArticleName = x.ArticleName
        });
    }

    if (request.Candy.HasValue && (bool)request.Candy)
    {
        // When its candy I want also articles from food category
        candyArticles= _context.Articles.Where(x => x.Active == true && x.ArticleType == ArticleType.Food || x.ArticleType==ArticleType.Candy).Select(x => new Article
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            ArticleName = x.ArticleName
        });
    }
    return await foodArticles.AsQueryable().Union(drinkArticles).AsQueryAble().Union(candyArticles);
}
```

Comment: thanks for help, check for my edit please. vote up!